# Prevent sql injection in dynamic code

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I need to execute dynamic string with sql query from C# code and prevent sql injection.

my code is like that:

```
internal static string Get_Running_Cars(string from, string to)
        {
            return string.Format(
                 " declare @from as datetime = '{0}'" +
                 " declare @to as datetime = '{1}'" +
                 " select  top 3 DATEDIFF(second,starttime,endtime) as sum,carname as name" +
                 " from cars" +
                 " where @from < starttime and @to > endtime ", from, to
                 );
        }
```

in that code I can insert malicious code into those string.

how can I use it safely ?
should I prevent those chars : `'`, `;`, `,` `-`?

Comment: It's very easy to move this code to a stored procedure where you can prevent sql injection easily by passing parameters. Is there any specific requirement to use dynamic query?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a dynamic query here.

Comment: i have more than 100 queries i need to inject, therefor i need to use dynamic query.
i cannot take 100 queries and convert all of them to stored procedure .
is there a good way to inject those queries ?

Comment: You don't have to use stored procedures, but you should use proper parameters instead of concatenating their string representation into the text of the query.

Comment: No you don't. Just use a parameterized query. With ADO.NET it takes about the same number of lines. With Dapper, just two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use EF, and therefore the best answer is to use 'SqlParameter'.

I build this object :

```
public class SqlQueryEntity
    {
        public string query { get; set; }
        public object[] _params { get; set; }
    }
```

and send it with DbRawSqlQuery.

I need to insert query with array of 'object' which contains :

```
new SqlParameter[] { 
                    new SqlParameter("from", from),
                    new SqlParameter("to", to)
                }
```

'to' and 'from' can contains Datetime object.

Answer (score 3):

The correct, easier, faster *and* safer way is to use parameterized queries. Assuming you use ADO.NET you can use the following method to create a parameterized query:

```
public SqlCommand BuildCarsCommand(DateTime from,DateTime to)
{
    var sql= "select  top 3 DATEDIFF(second,starttime,endtime) as sum,carname as name" +
         " from cars where @from < starttime and @to > endtime ";
    var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.Paramerers.AddWithValue("@from",from);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", to);

    return cmd;
}
```

You can execute the command with SqlCommand.ExecuteReader

Using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), it's even easier. A single line will pass the parameters:

```
 IEnumerable<Car> cars=connection.Query<Car>(sql,new {From=@from, To=@to});
```

This will create a SqlCommand internally, pass the parameters, execute the query and map the results to cars.

Entity Framework and most ORMs allow you to run parameterized queries too.

You'll have to specify which data access method you use if it isn't one of these.

In Entity Framework you can use LINQ to get this query, using [SqlFunctions.DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052(v=vs.110).aspx) to calculate the date difference :

```
var cars=from car in myDbContext.Cars
         where car.starttime >  from and car.endtime < to
         select new {
                      sum=SqlFunction.DateDiff("second", car.starttime,car.endtime),
                      name=carname
                     }
```

Comment: You don't need to write SQL for this query in EF, just use the proper `Where`, `Select` and `Take(3)` statements. To get the date difference you need the [SqlFunctions.DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052(v=vs.110).aspx) function

Comment: Were you to use [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb), it would sniff the types of your parameters and generate the method Execute(DateTime from, DateTime to). It would be impossible to do it wrong !

Answer (score 1):

Call it a rookie method if you will, but how about trying to parse the input into `DateTime` format beforehand?

[DateTime.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    internal static string Get_Running_Cars(string from, string to)
    {
        DateTime test1, test2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(from, out test1) || !DateTime.TryParse(to, out test2))
            return null;
        //else is optional here, to show logic
        return string.Format(
             " declare @from as datetime = '{0}'" +
             " declare @to as datetime = '{1}'" +
             " select  top 3 DATEDIFF(second,starttime,endtime) as sum,carname as name" +
             " from cars" +
             " where @from < starttime and @to > endtime ", from, to
             );
    }
```

Comment: First, this should be a comment. Second, if you create a DateTime, why not do the right thing and use a proper parameterized query? There's absolutely no reason to use string concatenation here.

Comment: this function is one of 150 functions. in this case you have datetime, in other case you different object. i cannot validate all of them. it is not a good answer, but thanks anyway

Comment: @EliadAyehu *don't* pass strings. Just use parameterized queries and pass the strongly typed values. It actually takes *less* code than the question or the answer to pass `DateTime` parameters to the query. How do you execute the queries? ADO.NET? EF ? Dapper? With Dapper you can use 2 lines in total, one of them for the string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I am "trying" the conversion to `DateTime`, just to check if its not an injection. I realize I might as well use the `DateTime`s created. Sadly, I am not very experienced in mysql. Personally, I `linq` everything.

Comment: You missed the point. You don't need to pass or convert anything. If you use a `SqlCommand` you can treat `@from` and `@to` as parameters and pass the DateTime values to it.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.

Comment: i use entity framework "_context.Database.SqlQuery(query)"